# External microphone not working on Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: windows-7, microphone

I just bought [Razer Carcharias headset](http://store.razerzone.com/store/razerusa/en_US/pd/productID.169415800/categoryId.35096300). I plugged them in my laptop. I can hear everything but the microphone is not working. As you can see in the screenshot bellow the internal mic is disabled by me and the razer's mic is recognized as Line in. Very strange. I tried the headset on my other laptop with the same windows and it works fine. Is there any way to add my new mic to the recordings list as External Mic?

PS: I can record sound with audacity while the mic is *line in* but the volume is really really low. I have to shout loud to record anything.

[image: recording options]

Answer (score 1):

Line-in inputs expect a higher signal level than microphones put out. Sometimes the line-in can be configured for a microphone. Otherwise you must use a microphone specific input (which most laptops I've seen have).

See more here: http://forum.audacityteam.org/viewtopic.php?f=27&t=9571

Comment: Any idea how to make it Microphone? I do not want line in at all.

Comment: I only know what the linked article says "You need to go into the laptop hardware services to figure out what to do." Each laptop is probably different. I would look for some kind of manufacturer/model specific utility and or the BIOS settings.